# MySQL error when deploying .NET application

Tags: mysql, connection

I'm attempting to install a MYSQL driven .net application to a Windows XP sp2 machine. The development machine is the same OS. The application and all connectivity work fine on my machine (the developers mantra), but I receive the following error on the installation machine when attempting to connect to the database.

As a side note, I can connect to the database via the OLE providers (via a UDL file)

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: command logging
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetKey(String key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue(String keyword, Object value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String key, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at CaseManager.Login.OpenConnection()
   at CaseManager.Login.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

CaseManager
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0

### CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/B3IS/Intelicase/CaseManager.exe

System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

BusinessEntities
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0

### CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/B3IS/Intelicase/BusinessEntities.DLL

MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 5.0.8.1
    Win32 Version: 5.0.8.1

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/5.0.8.1__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll

System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll

System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

```
Keyword not supported. Parameter name: command logging
```

This appears to be the relevant part.  The MySQL connection DSN is constructed from parameters which I guess are in your UDL file.  Only certain parameters are meaningful to a MySQL DSN, and unrecognized parameters will cause errors like this.

In this case, "`command logging`" appears to be the unrecognized parameter.

I don't know how you generated the UDL file, but apparently you entered some parameter(s) that were unrecognized.  Refer to documentation for the valid list of MySQL DSN parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the request, I removed that parameter as well as Allow Zero DateTime and it worked. Oddly enough, it works (in the code) on the development machine.  The driver and MDAC versions are the same on both machines.